# Serializing Child Classes in YamlDotNet

Tags: .net, serialization, yamldotnet

I am trying to add YAML serializing/deserializing in my application.  My class structure is such that several types derive from a base class.  When I attempt to serialize one of the child classes, it appears as though YamlDotNet does not include the properties specific to the child class.  As way of a simplified example:

```
Public Class BaseGrammar
    <YamlIgnore>
    Public Property FilePath As String

    Public Overridable Property Name As String
    Public Overridable Property Author As String
    Public Overridable Property Description As String
    Public Overridable Property Tags As BindingList(Of String)
End Class

Public Class AssignmentGrammar
    Inherits BaseGrammar

    Private _items As BindingList(Of  Item)

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As BindingList(Of Item)
    Get
        Return _items
    End Get
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Serialized using the following code:

```
Public Shared Sub ConvertXMLToYAML(ByVal sourcefileName As String,
                                   ByVal targetFileName As String)
    Dim grammar As BaseGrammar = OpenXML(sourcefileName)
    Dim serializer As New YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer(YamlDotNet.Serialization.SerializationOptions.Roundtrip)
    Using output As IO.TextWriter = IO.File.CreateText(targetFileName)
        serializer.Serialize(output, grammar)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Yields the following YAML:

```
!Grammars.Assignment.AssignmentGrammar,%20Grammars,%20Version=1.0.0.1,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=null
Name: Urban Gangs
Author: Lance Boudreaux
Description: Generates gangs for urban adventures.
Tags:
- Gang
- Encounter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was that my list on my child class was a readonly property and the YAML serializer doesn't support this.